# Python - reference a file in a different directory

Tags: python

I have to reference a file that exists in a different directory. This is just a text file, not a python module. I've read countless posts, most of which are about including modules. Nothing that I read is giving me a successful answer. Out of many attempts, this is my latest:

```
import os
REMOTE_FILE = open(os.path.join('/Users/me/Dropbox/otherfolder', 'text.txt'), "r")
decrypted = subprocess.check_output(['openssl', 'aes-128-cbc', '-d', '-in', REMOTE_FILE, '-base64', '-pass', key])
```

The program doesn't fail on this line immediately, but when I attempt to reference this file I get:

`TypeError: Can't convert '_io.TextIOWrapper' object to str implicitly`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `'/Users/me/Dropbox/otherfolder/'`?

Comment: How are you accessing the file? Your problem is probably there instead of in this line.

Comment: By using '/' at the start of your path, you are specifying an absolute path.  For example, on my system, I need to specify 'C:/' since I'm working on a Windows machine.

Comment: is the code snippet you posted the whole script? Maybe error occurs somewhere else?

Comment: @JPDurham - I'm on a Mac, so that is an absolute path. I tried `~/Dropbox/otherfolder/` but got the same result so I switched to the absolute path.

Comment: @ZhehaoMao and @zhangxaochen - If I copy the file into the same directory as my python script, and then just do `REMOTE_FILE = 'text.txt'` everything works fine. I think that this shows that the problem is one of referencing the file from another directory and not with the rest of my code. Do you agree?

Comment: Wait, you normally just assign a string to REMOTE_FILE? That would be what your problem is. Right now you are passing in a file object, not a string. You should just set REMOTE_FILE to the result of `os.path.join`.

Comment: Should REMOTE_FILE be a file stream or a file name? Don't you call open(REMOTE_FILE) somewhere else in your code?

Comment: How are you accessing the file?  If you need a file path combined with a file name, you only need `os.path.join('/Users/me/Dropbox/otherfolder', 'text.txt')` otherwise, you are referencing an open file, and NOT the file path combined with a file name.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks everyone. If someone posts that as a solution, I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `REMOTE_FILE = os.path.join('/Users/me/Dropbox/otherfolder', 'text.txt')` instead to get only the file path as a string and not an file object.

Answer (score 1):

Your `REMOTE_FILE` is a file object, not a string. Given your code, you probably meant to do:

```
import os
REMOTE_FILE = os.path.join('/Users/me/Dropbox/otherfolder', 'text.txt')
decrypted = subprocess.check_output(['openssl', 'aes-128-cbc', '-d', '-in', REMOTE_FILE, '-base64', '-pass', key])
```

Keeping `REMOTE_FILE` as a string, not an object.